# Why $F(x)=\int_1^x\frac{|sint|}{t^2+1}dt$ has $\infty$ points with horizontal tangent?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do we know that without evaluating the integral? Also, is it safe to say that it has a finite limit as $x\rightarrow +\infty$ but it is not monotonic?

Comment: The derivative is always nonnegative, so it is monotonically increasing. Using a comparison $$0 \le \int_1^x \dfrac{|\sin t|}{t^2+1}dt \le \int_1^x \dfrac{1}{t^2+1}dt$$ And we have $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x \dfrac{1}{t^2+1} dt = \lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan(x) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$ So, the integral is definitely bounded in the limit. Since it is monotonically increasing and bounded, the limit should exist.

Comment: Thank you @InterstellarProbe! :)

Comment: Oops, I did not apply the FToC correctly. It should be $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x \dfrac{1}{t^2+1}dt = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\arctan(x)-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem,
$$
F'(x)=\frac{|\sin x|}{x^2+1}
$$
which is equal to zero at infinitely many points $x=k\pi$ with integer $k$. At all those points the graph of $F$ has a horizontal tangent.